# Stop New Tab From Opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, mailchimp

I'm using mailchimp to create a signup sheet and every time the submit button is pressed, a new tab will open that confirms your subscription to the mailchimp email list. I want it to run as a sort of background process where no new tab is opened at all but the form is still submitted. Here is the code I currently have with MailChimp:

```
div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//standrtech.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=c330585c1144a0dd4bfd6d0df&amp;id=b7e663bdf4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <h2></h2>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>    <!--real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signup-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_c330585c1144a0dd4bfd6d0df_b7e663bdf4" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Get Early Access" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" onclick="submission();"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: use jquery-ajaxchimp https://github.com/scdoshi/jquery-ajaxchimp

Comment: remove `target="_blank"`

Comment: Probably the solution is to remove `onclick="submission();"` ... however, it would be better that you show us your `javascript` code related to the form

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that just changes some innerHTML on the page, which is something I implemented that does not affect links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `target="_blank"` from your `form` tag.

Comment: I tried that, but the link simply opens in the same window.

Comment: Yes, I would like the form to submit, but I do not want a new page to open that confirms the mailchimp signup

Comment: good thought, but now the form doesn't even send through. It does prevent the new tab, but that's probably because the form was not sent through.

Comment: Ah, you dont want a form. You want a button that will post via ajax. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp A little more involved, but will allow you to send the data and control the return.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am a little too late for this, but I have found the solution for future references.

*For 'classic' form only*

Looks like the HTML code is not copied properly. In the mailchimp embed form dashboard, look for the scripts after the outer div, the one containing the form, these scripts will validate your form. My embed form has two scripts after the outer div :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

second script may vary depending upon your form fields, but I think you definitely need to add the mc-validate.js to resolve this issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, it is because of the form validation script. i removed the script and do a simple email input text validation on my own.